# Is always true that $\partial Y$ is a closed set?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $Y\subseteq X$.

Is $\partial Y$ always a closed set?

Comment: Yes, it suffices to notice that $$\partial Y=\overline{Y}\cap \overline{X\setminus Y}$$ and $\overline{Y}$ and $\overline{X\setminus Y}$ are both closed.